# Polygonize.py: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'CreateDataSource'

Tags: raster, gdal, polygonize

**Given a topographic raster tif** of an european country where elevations are simplyfied to **either 0, either 200**.

**How to create a polygon ?**

---

**Comment**: With the following [polygonize.py](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_polygonize.html) command:

```
gdal_polygonize.py level200.tif -f "ESRI_Shapefile" level200.shp
```

I get to following error:

```
Creating output level200.shp of format ESRI_Shapefile.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/gdal_polygonize.py", line 164, in <module>
    dst_ds = drv.CreateDataSource( dst_filename )
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'CreateDataSource'
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not `ESRI Shapefile`? (No underscore)

Comment: If formerly used `ESRI Shapefile` but then got -at some stage- a feedback recommanding me to use ESRI_Shapefile. Now, it appear that `ESRI Shapefile` make the stuff work.

Comment: You may post your advice as an answer together with http://www.gdal.org/ogr/ogr_formats.html so I validate it :)

Comment: It's fine. You can answer it and get the rep. I have plenty :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'CreateDataSource'` means the format `-f` is incorrect.
2. Checking the manual : http://gdal.org/ogr/ogr_formats.html , the shape file format is `ESRI Shapefile` (no underscore).
3. Try without underscore:

   gdal_polygonize.py level200.tif -f "ESRI Shapefile" level200.shp

   it works. :)